# Fatal exception in Android app, but no stack trace

Tags: android

I start up my Android app, and it crashes. I see the following in the "Logcat" and "Run" tabs in Android Studio:

> 2021-02-01 17:58:39.448 6229-6311/com.mycompany.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
> Process: com.mycompany.app, PID: 6229

But there is no stack trace. I have no clue what could be causing it. Is there something I can do to get a stacktrace?

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox, 2020.3.1 Canary 5. I need to use the Canary version because I'm using Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Do you have better luck if you look at Logcat output using `adb logcat`?

Comment: It will be in your Android SDK. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and more about `adb logcat` [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat).

Comment: Nothing in logcat. It appears to only happen in the emulator, not on my device. I wanted to use the emulator for other reasons so this is annoying.